# Spring - Singleton factory instantiating prototype scoped beans

Tags: java, spring

Let's say I have a factory `CarFactory` that returns car object

```
class CarFactory {
      @Autowired
      ApplicationContext context;

      public Car get(String type) {
             if(type.equals("Merc")
                 return context.getBean(Merc.class);
             if(type.equals("Mclaren")
                 return context.getBean(Mclaren.class);
      }
}
```

Is there any way I can get rid of that `context.getBean` ? Somebody suggested be to inject Merc and Mclaren in the Factory and return them. But this would mean the same object is returned always. I need to create new Car objects everytime they are requested from the factory

Answer (score 4):

Configure in your SpringApplication (or what ever your config class is named) the following bean:

```
@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
public McLaren mcLarenProtyoe() {
    return new McLaren();
}
```

Also for Merc.

After that you can inject via `@Autowired` the bean. And because of the `@Scope("prototype")` Spring creates every time a new bean if it gets requested.